# How to send Json Array from java servlet to JSP using ajax?

Tags: java, jquery, json, ajax, jsp

I have obtained a json Array in my java servlet and I want to return it to my jsp to create a table. I am trying to use ajax but I can't obtain the data. I attach my code to obtain the table with a json that I have create manually in the jsp, but I want to use a json that I am obtaining in my java servlet.

JSP code:

```
var json = {"JsArray":[{"NAME":"John","SURNAME":"Doe","AGE":"30"},{"NAME":"Phil","SURNAME":"Jordan","AGE":"45"} ]};
    window.onload = function(){

    $( function() {
        var DataJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json));
        console.log(DataJson.JsArray.length);
        $("#resultados").append('<tr>' +
        '<td>NAME</td>'+
        '<td>SURNAME</td>' +
        '<td>AGE</td>');
        if(DatosJson.JsArray.length > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < DataJson.JsArray.length; i++){
              $("#resultados").append('<tr>' + 
              '<td align="center" style="text-align:left;">' + DataJson.JsArray[i].NAME + '</td>'+
              '<td align="center" style="text-align:left;">' + DataJson.JsArray[i].SURNAME + '</td>'+
              '<td align="center" style="text-align:left;">' + DataJson.JsArray[i].AGE + '</td>'+
            }
        } else {

            alert("No data found");
        }
    });

}
```

How can I get the json from the sevlet?
The java method generates a jsonArray and then redirects to the jsp with this line

```
return (mapping.findForward(target));
```

which redirects to the jsp using struts framework. How can I also return the jsonArray obtained in that java method and obtain it in the jsp with ajax?

Thank you in advanced :)

Comment: Return valid JSON. If you're asking how to return JSON from a Struts 1 action you can just search for that; there are many examples.

Comment: You get it on your servlet , so why dont you send it with attribute to your jsp ? *request.setAttribute("jsonarray",jsonarray);*

Comment: @KaramMohamed thank you for your help. It seems to work well. I have use a block of java code in my jsp that do this: JSONArray json = (JSONArray) request.getAttribute("resultado"); but now I need to use it in the javascript function, and when I try to put the json value in a hidden text-box to use it in the javascript using getelementbyid, I view this error: The method setValue(String) in the type BaseInputTag is not applicable for the arguments (JSONArray)